# Using ctrl+arrow to jump between punctuation in VSCode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

VSCode has a handy keybinding to jump by identifier using ctrl+arrow. However, I would like to change the behaviour of this slightly.

For example, my code looks like this: (`|` stands for the cursor)

```
|bar(foo.baz)
```

ctrl+right:

```
bar(|foo.baz)
```

I would like VSCode to treat the parentheses and other punctuation such as `.` as identifiers when I press ctrl+arrow so that each one has its own "stop". In my previous example I would like this to happen after repeated ctrl+right presses:

```
|bar(foo.baz)
bar|(foo.baz)
bar(|foo.baz)
bar(foo|.baz)
bar(foo.|baz)
bar(foo.baz|)
bar(foo.baz)|
```

This is what actually happens:

```
|bar(foo.baz)
bar(|foo.baz)
bar(foo.|baz)
bar(foo.baz)|
```

I've discovered that the Stack Exchange text editor has the behaviour I want, so you can try navigating some code in the Answer box using ctrl+arrow yourself to see what I mean.

Is there a setting or even extension that does this? I've tried googling but this problem is quite hard to describe in a short query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by)

Define the following keybinding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+right",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "(\\w+|.)",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```

You can tweak the regex if you want different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Binding to `cursorWordPartLeft` and `cursorWordPartRight` in keybindings.